# Inject constructor parameters using Unity

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

Suppose I have an interface called `IBlabla`, and its implemntation `Blabla`, like this :

```
public class Blabla : IBlabla
{
    Blabla(string endPoint) { }
}
```

Using StructureMap, I can easily inject a parameter to my constructor arguments, like this :

```
For<IBlabla>().Singleton().Use(() => new Blabla("myBinding"));
```

How can I acheive this using **`Unity`** ?

I have already tried all this :

```
container.RegisterType<IBlabla>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory((x, t, c) => new Blabla("myBinding")));
container.RegisterType<IBlabla, Blabla>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<string>("myBinding")));
```

But none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
container.RegisterType<IBlabla, Blabla>(new InjectionConstructor("myBinding"));
```